# Remove double slash after domain name (TLD) in Wordpress using .htacces

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have this URL: https://example.com//seo/ and want to remove the double slash after TLD and redirect to https://example.com/seo/

I'm using this code in Wordpress .htacces but not working (not redirect the doubleslash):

Full current code on my .htaccess on Worpdress, maybe it will help:

```
# Delete double slash
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/{2,}
    RewriteRule (.*) $1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/{2,}(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) %1/%2 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
# BEGIN WP-HUMMINGBIRD-CACHING
# Direktivy (řádky) mezi 'BEGIN WP-HUMMINGBIRD-CACHING' a 'END WP-HUMMINGBIRD-CACHING' jsou
# dynamicky generované a měly by být upravovány pouze pomocí filtrů WordPressu.
# Veškeré změny směrnic mezi těmito značkami budou přepsány.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0

<FilesMatch "\.(txt|xml|js)$">
ExpiresDefault A31536000
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(css)$">
ExpiresDefault A31536000
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(flv|ico|pdf|avi|mov|ppt|doc|mp3|wmv|wav|mp4|m4v|ogg|webm|aac|eot|ttf|otf|woff|svg)$">
ExpiresDefault A31536000
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|webp)$">
ExpiresDefault A31536000
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(txt|xml|js)$">
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000"
  </FilesMatch>

  <FilesMatch "\.(css)$">
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000"
  </FilesMatch>

  <FilesMatch "\.(flv|ico|pdf|avi|mov|ppt|doc|mp3|wmv|wav|mp4|m4v|ogg|webm|aac|eot|ttf|otf|woff|svg)$">
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000"
  </FilesMatch>

  <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|webp)$">
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
# END WP-HUMMINGBIRD-CACHING
```

Comment: So `https://example.com//seo/` remains as is? Can you post your full .htaccess?

Comment: Yes it remains as is. I'm added the full .htaccess code to question description :)

Comment: Test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Network tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get.

Comment: Try this URL: https://jumpacademy.cz//brno/ - there aren't 301/302 redirects in Network tab :(

Comment: I ran this via curl. It says `server: ATS`. Are you sure your .htaccess rules are executing for this URL?

Answer (score 0):

Check if this can work.

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    RedirectMatch 301 ^//(.*)$ http://example.com/$1
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Not working. Still remains as is http://example.com//seo/ (double flash after TLD). Added the full .htaccess to question description. Maybe it will help you.